# Get MAX serial ID for INSERT statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am currently creating an `INSERT` statement using a two-step process, which I am trying to condense into one step.

Right now I have a process that is tedious but works:

First, I run this query to get the next `SeriesID`:

```
SELECT MAX(serialNo) + 1 FROM Table1
```

Let's say it returns 54. Then next, I manually type the 54 into the `INSERT/SELECT`:

```
INSERT INTO Table1
    SELECT 54, NULL, 1, 'NEW', GETDATE(), Table2.TrackingID
    FROM Table2 
    LEFT JOIN Table3 ON Table3.pid = Table2.pid
    LEFT JOIN Table1 ON Table1.CustID = Table1.CustID
    WHERE Table3.packageNumber = '123456'
```

This works, but it is incredibly annoying to have to do the first query and then change the serial number manually every time. So I am trying to incorporate the query into the `INSERT`, but I am having no luck:

```
INSERT INTO Table1
    SELECT (MAX(serialNo) + 1), NULL, 1, 'NEW', GETDATE(), Table2.TrackingID
    FROM Table2 
    LEFT JOIN Table3 ON Table3.pid = Table2.pid
    LEFT JOIN Table1 ON Table1.CustID = Table1.CustID
    GROUP BY Table2.TrackingID, Table3.packageNumber
    HAVING Table3.packageNumber = '123456'
```

And this technically works as in doesn't throw an error, but instead of inserting the first column with 54 as I was hoping, it inserts it with a NULL.

Expected result:

```
   54|NULL|1|NEW|2022-06-10|98765
```

Actual result:

```
 NULL|NULL|1|NEW|2022-06-10|98765
```

How do I get the MAX serial number from Table1, so that I can use `MAX(serialNO) + 1` for the serial number in the next entry?

Comment: This `SELECT MAX(ID)+1` approach is a ***horribly bad idea*** in a busy system - you ***WILL*** for sure get duplicates, rather sooner than later! Use an `INT IDENTITY` column instead - or a `SEQUENCE`  - but **DO NOT** try to do this "manually" with `SELECT MAX(ID)+1` .....

Comment: Concurrency is going to cause this to fail, inserting multiple rows is going to be impossible, maintenence is going to be horrendous. Why on earth are you Not using an IDENTITY column?

Comment: @MatBailie I did not create this database.  I also don't have permissions to create, alter, or drop tables. So I have to work with what's there.

Comment: FYI: Best practice is to list the columns you are inserting into.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would consider using a [sequence for this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-sequence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16), but if you want to do it the way you're doing it, you need to put the full subquery in your `SELECT`:

```
INSERT INTO Table1
SELECT (select MAX(serialNo) +1 from Table1),NULL,1,'NEW',GETDATE(),Table2.TrackingID
  from Table2 
  left join Table3 on Table3.pid = Table2
  left join Table1 on Table1.CustID = Table1.CustID
GROUP BY Table2.TrackingID, Table3.packageNumber
HAVING Table3.packageNumber = '123456'
```

When you only have `MAX(serialNo)` it is getting the maximum after doing your joins and conditions, which is different than the maximum in the entire table.

The reason I suggest a `sequence` is to avoid potential concurrency issues. If multiple inserts are run at the same time, they might all return the same `max` and conflict. Even if you know that isn't currently possible, it's a safer design to avoid even potential concurrency issues.

Comment: Would you need to take an `UPDLOCK` or similar to ensure that only one instance of this statement is run at a time? i.e. address concurrency issues.

Comment: @DaleK I suggested a sequence so concurrency wouldn't be an issue. I have now edited my response to make the warning/advice more clear, but please feel free to add alternate methods of addressing the concurrency issue.